# Firebase Cloud Messaging sendEach function throws error while sending notifications: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been searching through the questions asked about this issue; however what I am looking for is a bit different.

While send() method of Firebase messaging works perfectly, sendEach() function throws the error. The desired behavior is that while it is certain other firebase functions in the code works as expected, sendEach function should send notification to all of the users in the arrays without an error. Note that also the function works in a bullMq worker.

We create an array of array of required data (Array<Array>). The users in the first array which contains about 490 user get the notification. But whenever it starts to second array it gives this error. It should send the notification to all of the groups in the array.

Here is my code:

```js
const usedTokens: string[] = [];
const smallDatas: Array<Array<Message>> = [[]];

for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
  if (index % 10000 === 0) {
    logService.logNotification(
      `namedNotification: {title: ${title}, body: ${body}, language: ${language}, operation: ${operation}}. Process: ${
        index + 1
      }/${users.length}`
    );
  }
  const user = users[index];

  if (usedTokens.includes(user.notificationToken!)) {
    continue;
  }

  if (smallDatas[smallDatas.length - 1].length > 490) {
    smallDatas.push([]);
  }
  smallDatas[smallDatas.length - 1].push({
    token: user.notificationToken!,
    data,
    notification: {
      body: body.replaceAll("@name", user.username!),
      title: title.replaceAll("@name", user.username!),
    },
    apns: { payload: { aps: { sound: "res_notifysound.aiff" } } },
    android: { notification: { sound: "res_notifysound" } },
  });

  usedTokens.push(user.notificationToken!);
}

for (let index = 0; index < smallDatas.length; index++) {
  if (index % 100 === 0) {
    logService.logNotification(
      `namedNotification - send: {title: ${title}, body: ${body}, language: ${language}, operation: ${operation}}. Process: ${
        index + 1
      }/${smallDatas.length}`
    );
  }
  await messagingService
    .of("namedNotification")
    .sendEach(smallDatas[index])
    .catch((error) => console.log("Notification Error : " + error));
}
```

tried to get new instance of FCM from the admin panel. but didn' work. it gives the same error